# Developing on the droid with mono without using monodroid

Tags: android, mono

Is there an alternative to developing apps on droid with mono without using monodroid?
I'm having trouble finding anything of the sort, searching(on both stackoverflow and google) comes up with nothing but links to monodroid.

Comment: You mean that you want to develop in C# but without using Mono?

Comment: I mean develop for the Android with Mono, but without Monodroid. Monodroid is a proprietary software for the Android(That I can't afford on my own budget). Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this helpful: http://www.koushikdutta.com/search/label/Android%20Mono